# composer global require laravel/installer is not working on my machine

Tags: php, laravel-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9qy0.png)

PHP- Version : 8
Composer Version : 2

but i can't install laravel on my machine.
Operating System : Zorin OS 16

Answer (score 4):

Faced the same issue before but now solved it.
Run the commands below in terminal.
`$ composer global require "laravel/installer"`
`$ export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

The above commands should solve the issue, create a new laravel app as normal.
`$ laravel new App_Name`

Comment: In my case, `COMPOSER_HOME` points to `/Users/<user>/.composer` (`~/.composer`).
Use `composer config --global home` to find out where your home directory is.
(Source: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home)

Then, you can adjust the command accordingly:
`export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`